# Jenkins worklflow - AD group as submitter for manual approval

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have a jenkins workflow, want to implement manual approval for members of AD group.

Using following code

```
input message: ''Deployment look good?', ok: 'deploy to Production', submitter: 'ADGroup'
```

If i am using user id the approval process works fine. 
If I am using an AD group it is not working. I even tied jenkins role.

In Jenkins [documentation](https://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cookbook/_workflow_dsl_keywords.html#__literal_input_literal_input) it is mentioned that

> submitter: Optional user/group name who can approve this.

How to specify group name as submitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AD group name ought to be accepted. Browse to `/whoAmI` to verify your group memberships as seen by Jenkins, and check for typos.